# "baseclass" for templates?

Tags: c++, templates, base-class, derived

(sorry for the vague title)

I have a base class B with various derived classes D1, D2, etc.

Furthermore I have a template

```
template <class T> Storage;
```

Now each of the derived classes has a different version of the Storage class

```
class D1 : public class B {
   Storage<int> *myStorage;
   void action1();
   void specific_D1_action();

   // other stuff...
}

class D2 : public class B {
   Storage<float> *myStorage;
   void action1();
   void specific_D2_action();

   // other stuff...
}
```

`D1::action1()` and `D2::action1()` use their respective `myStorage` and have exactly the same code. However, the actual template parameters of the respective `myStorage` objects differ.

Is it possible to have a kind of "base class" for all versions of Storage,
so that I can define myStorage and action1 in the base class B (instead of D1, D2,...) to avoid code duplication?

I think I can't "templatify" the base class B, because of the specific actions in the derived classes.

(this example is very simplified - in the real case the template parameters are complex classes)

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want. It would help if you posted some code you expect in `specific_Dx_action`.

Comment: `class D1 : public class B` ? Seeing your code, it seems that you need to first learn the basic syntax of C++.

Comment: "I think I can't "templatify" the base class B, because of the specific actions in the derived classes", why? Check the answer below,  you could apply the template on B and get rid of DerivedBase?

Comment: @Nawaz That would probably explain why i never got a program running all these years... ;)

Answer (score 8):

Create a base class that inherits from the `B` base class and takes a template parameter?

```
class B
{
    // ...
};

template<typename T>
class DerivedBase : public B
{
    Storage<T> *myStorage;
    void action1();
};

class D1 : public DerivedBase<int>
{
    void specific_D1_action();
};

class D2 : public DerivedBase<float>
{
    void specific_D2_action();
};
```

Comment: Thank You Joachim - i wasn't aware you could derive from instantiated templates

Comment: @user1479670: An instantiated template is a full type, and can be used for everything a type can be used for.

Comment: typedef can be quite useful here, especially if you're going to be putting these into  other templates.